# IntelliJ IDEA can't compile with big size library

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

I have a library with huge amount of classes. This jar size = 276MB. When I include this jar to module dependencies, all seems fine. I can use import classes in editor. Navigate to classes and decompile them (Ctrl+N) and so on... All working fine.

But when I try compile this project, compiler tells me: `"Can't find symbol class ....", "package ... does not exist"`.

Gradle compiles fine with this lib. Can JAR size provide problems like this?

Comment: From the looks of it, it would appear to be classpath related.  Are you certain IntelliJ can find the required package and classes?  Are you using the Gradle plugin to keep your classpath in sync within IntelliJ?

Comment: I try it with gradle, without gradle. Result is same. Navigation in editor is fine, but can't compile. I can send this jar.

Comment: If it compiles fine with Gradle, but it doesn't compile simply using IntelliJ, verify that your classpath is setup correctly.

Comment: What classpath are you talking about? To the JDK? Idea can't find classes in this library when compile project. With JDK all fine.

Comment: If you're not using Gradle to compile your project inside IntelliJ, then IntelliJ needs to know where all your libraries are, that's what the classpath is.  It contains all the required libraries for your project.

Comment: Yeah, I attach this jar to module dependansies as I wrote above. How without this I may navigate to that classes?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58960/discussion-between---and-patrick-grimard).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. This is not IDEA bug. This jar was a ZIP64 format... so, and java compiler bellow version 1.7_55 can't operate with it https://blogs.oracle.com/xuemingshen/entry/zip64_support_for_4g_zipfile. In my project i use 1.6 java, gradle use latest, so.

When i change project SDK problems is gone.

Answer (score 1):

To me It looks like IDE bug.

Try the following things:

1. Try File->Invalidate Caches
2. Try putting the the jar project correctly
3. Try recompiling the jar in the IDE (if you have the jav code) and relate to your main project.

If the above don't work, you need to report a bug.